# Convert haml code to erb in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What will be the erb code for below haml code?

```
content_for :head do
  = stylesheet_link_tag "plupload.queue"
  = javascript_include_tag "plupload/plupload.full.min", "plupload/jquery.plupload.queue.min"
  = javascript_tag do
    = render "plupload.js"
```

photos_container

```
= render :partial => "photo", :collection => @photos
```

uploader

```
%p You browser doesn't have HTML5, Flash or Silverlight support.
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967262/is-there-a-good-haml-erb-html-converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise to read HAML and ERB documentation as it basics for your development process. There is a lot of information around this, so try to use search before you ask.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html
- http://haml.info/

Your ERB code:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "plupload.queue" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "plupload/plupload.full.min", "plupload/jquery.plupload.queue.min" %>
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
    <%= render "plupload.js"%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<div id="photos_container">
  <%= render :partial => "photo", :collection => @photos %>
</div>

<div id="uploader">
  <p>You browser doesn't have HTML5, Flash or Silverlight support.</p>
</div>
```

In Rails 3 you can optimize your code, if you use app/views/photos/_photo.html.erb partial. Rails determines the name of the partial to use by looking at the model name in the collection.

Like this:

```
<div id="photos_container">
  <%= render @photos %>
</div>
```

Read about rendering in Rails 3:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render